# Unity : Building an AssetBundels takes too long time, so i want to partially build. Anything i can do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

All AssetBunlde build takes a long time.

I want reduce the used time. So I try that

`(AssetBundleManifest.BuildAssetBundles(string outputPaht, assetBundleBuild[] bundles, .....)`

method, but It takes a long time, too;

Anything i can do?
Help me.

Answer (score 0):

**short answer**

You can not "partially" build assetbundles, the only solution to that would be to build less bundles by removing some of the assetbundle labels so they do not get build.

**Long answer**

Since Unity 5.6 there is a new tool made by unity called the assetbundle browser, making working with assetbundles a lot easier and faster.

If you have Unity 5.6 or later you may want to consider the new AssetBundle browser from unity. which you can find more detailed info on [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Browser.html)

The new AssetBundle browser has a new and improved pipeline which will reduce the time needed to build assetbundles. Additionally it gives a clearer, and more easy to use overview of which assetbundles you want to build, and comes with a gui to change settings such as build target etc.

Still building AssetBundles will be a bit of a time consuming task since quite alot is going on in the background. Buiding times are also heavily dependant on the amount of AssetBundles you are building and for what platform you are trying to build Windows as the targeted platform is especially slow, but for example Android will build alot faster. Keep this in mind before building and make sure you are truly ready to build.

To get started with the new AssetBundle browser you'll have to [download it here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/AssetBundles-Browser) from unity's github page, and place the contents in the /assets/ folder. if this all is done correctly you will find the AssetBundle browser under Window > Assetbundle Browser.

Hope this helps

~Remy